# Underscore/Backbone template events

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

In underscore.js templates, is there a way to get the data of the template from a click event? For example:

```
geocoder.geocode({
                'address' : $(this.el).find("input[name=locationSearchText]").val()
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (results && status && status == 'OK') {
                    this.results = results;
                    var list =_.template("<ul><% _.each(results, function(result){  %><li><%= result.formatted_address %></li><% })%></ul>");
                    $el.find("#search-results").html(list);
                }else{
                    alert("SOMETHING WENT WRONG!");
                }
            });
```

And then in backbone on the view:

```
    events: {
        'click #search-results li': function(data){ 'the data of the `result` that was passed to the template in the each'}
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

In the past what I've done is stick the data I want in a `data-` attribute of the element, like this:

```
var list =_.template("<ul>
    <% _.each(results, function(result){  %>
        <li data-foo=\"<%= result.foo %>\"><%= result.formatted_address %></li>
    <% })%>
</ul>");
```

And in the callback I could retrieve it like this:

```
'click #search-results li': function(ev){
    var foo = $(ev.currentTarget).data('foo');
}
```

But if you need to access the whole `result` object, rather than storing it in the DOM you could do something similar to what [CanJS's element callback](http://canjs.com/docs/can.EJS.html#section6) does, where you store the object with `jQuery.data` on the element:

```
this.results = results;
var list =_.template("<ul><% _.each(results, function(result){  %><li><%= result.formatted_address %></li><% })%></ul>");
$el.find("#search-results").html(list).find('li').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).data('result', results[i]);
});
```

Then retrieve it in the callback using `$(ev.currentTarget).data('result')`.

Comment: You just beat me to it... though I didn't flesh mine out yet.